# EF core connection string between two docker containers

Tags: docker, entity-framework-core, docker-container, ef-core-2.1

I have two containers:

- .Net Core web API
- MS SQL Server.

I'm using entity framework core for database operations, and I'm trying to connect to the database with a connection string.

```
Data Source={hostname};Database=...;Initial Catalog=...;User ID=...;Password=...;
```

What works:

- `hostname=localhost` for updating locally with `dotnet ef database update`
- `hostname=172.X.X.X` for communicating from API to the DB, where the ip address it the one docker assigns to the database

The problem is that I want to set the hostname to the name of the container. However, it doesn't work despite seeing a lot of examples online such as this article: https://blog.sixeyed.com/windows-weekly-dockerfile-17-connecting-containers/

Currently using Linux Docker on my windows machine. The containers are within the same "bridge" network.